# Matching a packet in OVS

Tags: switch, openflow, packet-path

I'm new to OVS and I'm working on an OVS project, and i read a lot of documents about it but i didn't find anything that can make things clear to me about matching a packet and in userspace and datapath and if there is a match then what the ovs do ?
Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Things happens in kernel module(datapath) are very fast compared to `userspace`.

First packet hits the kernel module, at very first time there will be no cache. It will send the packet to userspace, then the packet is routed. In this process, the kernel module make `hash` cache of the header of packet.

So, the subsequent packet hits the kernel module, then OVS calculate the `hash` for the header of the subsequent packet and checks whether that hash already present or not. If it is there, it will route or send it to userspace. Check [this video](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLjbrwxvnLAhVCG6YKHYQQB7gQtwIIGzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dd2r68RfjxlM&usg=AFQjCNEb8Ner1LoASIHVo6fhppcPdA5aKQ&sig2=wxHOVUEFjQixi00iFsD-YA&bvm=bv.118443451,d.dGo) and [PPT](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbvLCax_nLAhVKv5QKHUBYB6EQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenvswitch.org%2Fslides%2FOpenStack-131107.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFo5Pfuy_pF6ehfFx3IsUuLR4VL6g&sig2=gk73TUb1YOuG1hbVUSX5Kw&bvm=bv.118443451,d.dGo)

[image: OVS]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Packets received into OVS hit the datapath module first. If there is an entry in the flow cache, corresponding action is applied on the packet. If there is no entry, an "upcall" happens and the packet is sent to the user space over netlink protocol via the dpif interface. Actually there are queues present to buffer upcalls to the userspace where the handling is done.

Thanks.